# Android: JSONDownloader return empty string

Tags: android

I try to read JSON file from server but when I pass this URL to it , it does not return the JSON objects,
and there is no error or exception occures , just it returns empty string and I don't want this ,

here is the URL for test: http://famila1.ir/khabgah/get_khabgah_cash.php

this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.aqamamad.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is the code:

```
public class JSONDownloader
{
    public String downloadURL( String strUrl )
    {
        String data = "";

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL( strUrl );

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            connection.setDoInput(true);

            connection.connect();

            InputStream myStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( myStream ) );

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;

            while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                sb.append( line );
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

            connection.disconnect();

            myStream.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            /*
              *Log.i( "MatiMessage" , "error in JSONDownloader in downloadURL() -> " + e.toString() );
              */
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Anybody know the problem with this code?

Comment: Have you tried the same using okhttp?

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick can you explain more ?!

Comment: Is it throwing any exception?

Comment: Now you are using httpurl to get data from the api. I am suggesting you to do the same thing with okhttp library or retrofit. An android library used to get /post datas.

Comment: What response are you getting ? or error log?

Comment: @Alex no error or exception , just empty string return from this code , and i dont know why empty is it.

Comment: @UmangBurman  no error or exception , just empty string return from this code , and i dont know why empty is it.

Comment: @UmangBurman  no error or exception , just empty string return from this code , and i dont know why empty is it.

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick i didnt work with these libraries before , could you post your answer or give me a tutorial link , tnx

Comment: @MohammadSeyedmahmudi Please check my answer. User trim()

Comment: Did it work? @MohammadSeyedmahmudi

Comment: Check if you've added internet permission in Manifest.xml if Alex's answer doesn;t work, Post a screenshot of your manifest file here. You may be missing something there. So we'll check and let you know.

Comment: @UmangBurman i checked alex's answer but it is still return null string , i will add my manifest file to my post just 1sec.

Comment: @Alex not yet i used trim not useful

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @UmangBurman nothing changed

Comment: Bro, You might be getting some error or response. Are you getting response as null or exception as null?

Comment: Are you getting in `data` as null?

Comment: @UmangBurman yes method return variable data as null

Answer (score 2):

```
public void getContent(String url) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;

                try {
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json,text/html");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "");

                    try {
                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                                "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line).append("\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                        is.close();
                        conn.disconnect();
                        return sb.toString();

                    } catch (SocketException e) {// connection reset
                        Log.d(TAG, "SocketException: " + e);
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {// connection reset
                        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                // You get the result here

            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Http connection is considered as time consuming action, so you need put it into another thread instead of the UI thread

Comment: i checked my connection and it is fine , i use this class for my list view in my fragment class i created an object of my JSONDownloader and passed the test url to it but it still return a null string  :(

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

i use this permission for internet access in my manifest file , i thing it should work for me , but it is not :| :(

Comment: i add my manifest file to my question check it out please @Alex

Comment: check my updated answer. As Http connection is considered as time consuming action, so you need put it into another thread.

Comment: the method that you have written is not returning any string and it is void type , how can i get the result as a string of this method ? i tried to get result from the line which you have commented in it , but i get nothing

Comment: You get the result here @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s)  .... You can call next method from here and pass string s as method parameter.

Comment: not useful again :( is it possible to be some thing wrong with fragment ? because i am using my list view in my fragment

Comment: i dont have github account but i share my project files in my personal website ,
here is direct link for download : http://famila1.ir/MyApplication.zip
check out my app please tnx